# How do I unit test an object of arrays in React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a parent component `CafeList.js` that makes a service call to firebase and returns cafe data as arrays within an object. I pass this entire object as props to `Cafe.js` where it is mapped over, and properties are destructured out and rendered (eg, the cafe name: `name`).

I want to write a test to check that the `name` element is being rendering in the `Cafe.js` component, but I'm not sure how to access props that are in the form of an array or object. I'm new to RTL so am a bit lost - any suggestions?

***CafeList.jsx***

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import db from '../fbConfig'
import Cafe from './Cafe'

const CafeList = () => {
    const [cafes,setCafe] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        let cafeArray = []
        db.collection('cafes')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(cafe => {
                cafeArray.push(cafe)
            })
            setCafe(cafeArray)
        })
    },[])



   const [...cafeData] = cafes.map((cafe) => {
        const { name, photoURL } = cafe.data()
        return { name:name,photoURL:photoURL, id:cafe.id}
    })

    return(
        <div className="cafe-container-container">
            <h2 className = 'main-subheading'>Reviews</h2>
            <Cafe cafes = {cafeData}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CafeList
```

***Cafe.jsx***

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Cafe = ({ cafes }) => {

  return (
    <div className="cafe-grid">
      {
      cafes.map((cafe) => {
        return (
          <Link
            to={`/cafe-reviews/${cafe.id}`}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#686262" }}
          >
            <div className="cafe-container">
              <h3>{cafe.name}</h3>
              <img src={cafe.photoURL}></img>
            </div>
          </Link>
        )
      })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
export default Cafe
```

***cafe.test.js***

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Cafe from '../components/Cafe'

test('is cafe name rendering', () =>{
    render(<Cafe cafe = {[]}/>)
    const nameElement = screen.getByText(//the cafe name as passed by props)
    expect(nameElement).toBeInTheDocument
})
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the interface slightly so that you pass in an array of simple objects to `Cafe`, not an array of complex objects with a `data()` method.  In `CafeList`, create an array of simple objects with `id`, `name`, `photoURL` and pass that to `Cafe` instead.  Then if you log the array you're passing, it should be simple to capture that array and use it in a test.

Comment: Hi @user2740650, I changed my code accordingly to pass down the cafe data as a simple object. Still a bit unsure though of how to capture this data in a test?

Comment: Great!  Now it should be as simple as changing that one `render` line in your test case to be something like `render(<Cafe cafe = {[{id: "the-id", name: "the-name", photoURL: "some-url"]}/>)`.  And then you can assert that various content is in the document.